# Does “think much of” mean “remember” in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have this paragraph in my English textbook:

> Loyalty is the third quality. Two friends must be loyal to each
> other and they must know each other so well that there can be no
> suspicions between them. We do not **think much of people** who readily
> believe rumours and gossip about their friends. Those who are easily
> influenced by rumours can never be good friends.
> <sub>Source: *English 11,* via [Speaking English](http://language123speaking.blogspot.com/2009/12/friendship-qualities.html)</sub>

Looking up the meaning in Longman dictionary, I found 2 meanings of “thinking much of people” which are confusing to me:

> **1.** to **remember** something
>
> *Ex: I can’t think of the name of the hotel we stayed in.*
>
> **2.** to behave in a way that shows that you want to **treat other people well**:
>
> *Ex: He’s always thinking of other people.* 
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “think” from the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/think_1)</sub>

Which one is more relevant to the phrase I have written? Can I re-write that phrase like this?

> We do not **remember** people who readily believe rumours and gossip about their friends.

Comment: Scroll down to [definition 33 in Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/think_1#p008-000596442): **not think much of somebody/something:** to not like someone or something very much. _I didn't think much of his new girlfriend._

Comment: Longman is great, just remember to search for the phrase again (`ctrl + F` on the page) once you get to the list of definitions.

Comment: See also definition 34: **think highly of somebody/something** *also* **think a lot of somebody/something**: to admire or respect someone or something: *Your boss must think highly of you if she gives you so much responsibility.* and definition 36: **think badly of somebody** *also* **think less of somebody** *formal*: to disapprove of someone or what they have done. (The definitions you quoted are simply for the word “think”, and do not address the “think much of” idiom.)

Comment: Be careful not to confuse **think much of** with **think much about someone/something**, which _does_ mean "to have someone/something in one's thoughts frequently".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To think much of someone is to think highly of them.  To give them high regard or respect.

It is very often seen in the negative.  *I don't think much of him* is used to refer to someone you dislike or disrespect for some reason.

I've never come across the expression being used in either of the senses that you quote in your question.

So your example; *We don't think much of people who readily believe rumours* indicates that such people are not highly regarded.

Comment: +1 "don't think much of" means the same as "think poorly of" or "think little of". "Think much of" means the same as "think highly of" or "think well of"

Answer (score 6):

To "think much of people" is to *have a high opinion of them.*

It is NOT to "remember" or think about them "a lot."